# Isekai fantasy manga with a male lead that reincarnates as a child with magic

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

He reincarnated as a child in his past life/year and wanted to be strong so he trains by doing magic.

There is a chapter where he wakes up early to set traps before a monster attacks the villagers, and his parents didn’t know anything. When they all woke up, they celebrated his birthday, and they saw a big earth gate made by the male lead, and when they heard the monster, he already closed the gate and fought it.

He has a female childhood best friend that he teaches magic to; I remember it’s his sister, I think. Please help me if you know this, it’s been years since I read this and I can’t remember the title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to this site. Was this story in full colour, or mostly black & white? What colour was the MC's hair? Also, what happened before he reincarnated? Was he a regular person living somewhere like Japan or Korea originally, or did he always live in a fantasy world? And what were the circumstances of his death?

Answer (score 2):

Since I stumbled across this site when I was looking for the very same manga, I figured I'd might as well save you the hours I spent until I found it. *[Shi ni Modori, Subete wo Sukuu Tame ni Saikyou e to Itaru](https://myanimelist.net/manga/125035/Shi_ni_Modori_Subete_wo_Sukuu_Tame_ni_Saikyou_e_to_Itaru)*, aka *As he respawn, he aims for the invincibility to save everything*

[image: Front cover of Shi ni Modori, Subete wo Sukuu Tame ni Saikyou e to Itaru]

> Eric has had a hard life. At the age of 16, his village was overrun by monsters, who killed his friends and family. He soon became a soldier, but failed to save the life of the woman he loved. In the end, he died on the battlefield, surrounded by the bodies of those who he couldn’t protect. When Eric wakes up, he finds himself in a baby’s body. Realizing he has been reincarnated, he quickly wonders what is going on before he gets another shocker: the man and woman who are raising him are in fact his previous life’s parents! That’s right - Eric was reincarnated, but as himself. No alternate worlds, no skill trees, just his memories sent back to the moment he popped out of his mother. Armed with the knowledge of his past self, Eric vows to save everyone now that the universe has pushed the reset button for him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please [edit] some details into your answer that would help motivate why you think this is what the OP is looking for?